# Plot bar graph using matplotlib with different dataframe shape

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have three different Data frame as below.first two has the shape as (4,) and the last has the shape as (2,). How to convert the shape of the data frame?

When I try to plot all the three in a bar graph, the last DF fails with "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape"

How to plot the DF3 in the same bar graph by showing "Empty" and "Invalid" as 0.

DF1:

```
Validity

Empty               2672

InValid              581

Multiple Entries     282

Valid               5526

Name: Lifecycle, dtype: int64
```

DF2:

```
Validity

Empty                1920

InValid               471

Multiple Entries     2325

Valid               33446

Name: Lifecycle, dtype: int64
```

DF3:

```
Validity

Multiple Entries    10334

Valid               11984

Name: Lifecycle, dtype: int64
```

Below is my code.

```
glot = sample_lot_number.groupby("Validity")

vlot = sample1_lot_number.groupby("Validity")

dplot = Data_Package_Lot_Number.dplot.groupby("Validity")

ind = np.arange(4)

width = 0.15

ax = plt.subplot()

p1 = ax.bar(ind+width,glot.Lifecycle.count(), width)

p2 = ax.bar(ind,vlot.Lifecycle.count(), width)

p3 = ax.bar(ind-width,dplot.Lifecycle.count(), width)

ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)

ax.set_xticklabels(("Empty","InValid","Multiple Entries","Valid"))
```

Comment: Use `pandas.DataFrame.reindex` to reindex your dataframe and set the missing ones. It'll fill with `NaN` but you can change that to `0` if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

@busybear gave the right answer in the comment. Your code is not runnable. If I would make a guess, you can try the following code:

```
glot = sample_lot_number.groupby("Validity")
vlot = sample1_lot_number.groupby("Validity")
dplot = Data_Package_Lot_Number.dplot.groupby("Validity")
df1 = glot.Lifecycle.count()
df2 = vlot.Lifecycle.count().reindex(df1)
df3 = dplot.Lifecycle.count().reindex(df1).fillna(0)

ind = np.arange(4)
width = 0.15
ax = plt.subplot()
p1 = ax.bar(ind+width, df1, width)
p2 = ax.bar(ind, df2, width)
p3 = ax.bar(ind-width, df3, width)
ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(("Empty","InValid","Multiple Entries","Valid"))
```